# How to create filter by ng-model in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have this code

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputFood" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Component</label>
      <br>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputFood{{ $index + 1}}" id="inputFood{{$index+1}}" required ng-model="foodForm.inputFood[$index+1]" placeholder="Type a component" autocomplete="off" ng-keyup="doCheck($index+1)">
      </div>

    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
      <ul ng-show="showListFood" class="foodList{{$index+1}}">
        <li ng-click="showFood(foodN.food_name, foodN.food_id)" ng-repeat="foodN in foodName| filter : foodForm.inputFood.$index+1">
          <span>{{ foodN.food_name}}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
```

And i'm trying to filter list by ng-model in ng-repeat, but sadly i don't succeed. I would be very thankful for some help.

This is the example [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/g88quyk1/10/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

```
    app.controller('foodCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.foodName = [];
        $scope.foodForm = [];
        $scope.foodsComponent = [{
            id: 'comp1',
            inputFood: ''
        }];


        $scope.foodName = [{
            "food_name": "egg"
        }, {
            "food_name": "bread"
        }, {
            "food_name": "apple"
        }];


        $scope.showListFood = true;
        $scope.isFood = false;

        $scope.doCheck = function(index) {

            $(function() {

                if ($scope.foodForm.inputFood.index != "" &&        $scope.foodForm.inputFood.index != undefined) {

                    $scope.showListFood = true;

                } else {

                    $scope.showListFood = false;
                    $scope.isFood = false;
                }

            });
        };


        $scope.addComponent = function() {

            var newItemNo1 = $scope.foodsComponent.length + 1;
            $scope.foodsComponent.push({
                id: 'comp' + newItemNo1,
                inputFood: ''
            });

        };
    });

</script>
```

```
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addComponent()">ADD</button>
        <div class="spacer"></div>


        <div ng-repeat="comp in foodsComponent">
            <fieldset>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputFood" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Component</label>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputFood{{ $index + 1}}" id="inputFood{{$index+1}}" required ng-model="foodForm.inputFood[$index+1]" placeholder="Type a component" autocomplete="off" ng-keyup="doCheck($index+1)">
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <ul ng-show="showListFood" class="foodList{{$index+1}}">
                        <li ng-click="showFood(foodN.food_name, foodN.food_id)" ng-repeat="foodN in foodName| filter : foodForm.inputFood[$index+1]">
                            <span>{{ foodN.food_name}}</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the filter like this 
 `filter : foodForm.inputFood[$index+1]"`

```
<li ng-click="showFood(foodN.food_name, foodN.food_id)" ng-repeat="foodN in foodName| filter : foodForm.inputFood[$index+1]">
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g88quyk1/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Filter does not work with ng-repeat in Angular 1.x based on this Angularjs doc
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Please read the link above.
I copy a couple of paragraphs from ngRepeat link:

*The built-in filters orderBy and filter do not work with objects, and will throw an error if used with one.

If you are hitting any of these limitations, the recommended workaround is to convert your object into an array that is sorted into the order that you prefer before providing it to ngRepeat. You could do this with a filter such as [toArrayFilter](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-toArrayFilter) or implement a $watch on the object yourself.*

So, one solution could be create a new sorted array of Foods before you use with ng-repeat.  The other solution could be use toArrayFilter solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set showListFood to true initially and chnage filter syntax
See this : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t984xw09/)

```
(1)  $scope.showListFood =true
(2)ng-repeat="foodN in foodName| filter : foodForm.inputFood[$index+1]"
```

Comment: it's half correct. i need the list to be hidden, and filterd by the same input. i've change in checking part insted of $scope.foodForm.inputFood.index i change it to $scope.foodForm.inputFood[index]. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/g88quyk1/17/). but now when i add some more inputs, when i type in one, all the lists are open

Comment: so wat you exactly want?

Comment: look at the last example in the comment above. i want the i type in one input only the list under the input will show filtered, and not show me all the other lists.

Comment: Excellent! what did you do?

Comment: i have set ng show as property of showListFood of pushed element and set to false initially

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.showListFood = true;
    $scope.foodName = [
    {
      "food_name": "alpha"
    },
    {
      "food_name": "beta"
    }
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputFood" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Component</label>
      <br>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputFood{{ $index + 1}}" id="inputFood{{$index+1}}" required ng-model="foodForm.inputFood" placeholder="Type a component" autocomplete="off" ng-keyup="doCheck($index+1)">
      </div>

    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
      <ul ng-show="showListFood" class="foodList{{$index+1}}">
        <li ng-repeat="foodN in foodName | filter : foodForm.inputFood">
          <span>{{ foodN.food_name}}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```